# Automate file downloads from url

Tags: url

*Not sure whether this is the right place to ask but here I go...*

Is there a utility (preferably free) available that can download docs if we pass the url as input ?

For example I have a document available in the following URL.

https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/kvntest1/readme.txt

Upon using this utility I would like to be able to grab the document and store it in my machine.

Is this possible ?

Our main objective would be to operate this in bulk for about 200-300 URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you got url's per line within a file **links.txt**:

```
url1
url2
url3
....
```

you can use wget as follows on both Linux, Window, etc:

```
wget -i links.txt
```

you can put it into background with -b on Linux, MAC and to continue unfinished downloads:

```
wget -b -c -i links.txt
```